# How to display custom PHP error messages in CodeIgniter 1.7.2

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to show a custom error view instead of the default error page for
production environment.
I have changed little in `exception.php`.

```
function show_php_error($severity, $message, $filepath, $line)
{
  $severity = ( ! isset($this->levels[$severity])) ? $severity : $this->levels[$severity];

  $filepath = str_replace("\\", "/", $filepath);

  // For safety reasons we do not show the full file path
  if (FALSE !== strpos($filepath, '/'))
  {
    $x = explode('/', $filepath);
    $filepath = $x[count($x)-2].'/'.end($x);
  }

  if (ob_get_level() > $this->ob_level + 1)
  {
    ob_end_flush();
  }
  //REMOVE IF ISSUE IN APLHA3       
  if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost'){
    ini_set('sendmail_from','info@penpencileraser.com');
    $error_message='Location: '.$filepath;
    $error_message.="\n\n Message: ".$message.' \n\n Line Number :'.$line;
    $error_message.="\n\n Path: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    mail('ramya.p@abc.com','PenPencilEraser Error',$error_message);
    if(APPFOLDER=='frontend'){  
      header("location: ".LINKURL.'errors/common');
      exit;
    }
  }
  //ob_start();
  //include(APPPATH.'errors/error_php'.EXT);
  //$buffer = ob_get_contents();
  //ob_end_clean();
  //echo $buffer;
}
```

I get the error

```
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.
```

Comment: Where have you defined `LINKURL`??? and inside `errors/common` have you set any `header`???

Comment: i have defined LINKURL in application/config/config.php

Comment: i haven't set header in error/commom

Comment: This `LINKURL` points to your `APPPATH` or outside `APPPATH`???

Comment: LINKURL points My APPPATH not outside

Comment: So basically U've created your own controller for displaying errors right???

Comment: yes i have create my own controller

Comment: I find `LINKURL` as possible suspect: My guess is, the url U defined is not correct. Try `echo LINKURL.'errors/common';` and confirm whether the path is correct...!

Comment: it is print the correct url

Comment: i think its not good to redirect, since if there is a general problem that occurs even on the error page itself there is an infinite redirect.

Comment: is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @RanjithSivasamy : May be [**Link1**](http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/codeigniter_404) and [**Link2**](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html) will help you...

Comment: thank a lot, i will be check the links